# Regex to split following line into various fields?

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex.
Need some help.

I want to have a regex that would give me the following o/p for given i/p in java.

Input string

```
1. AB,CD,EF,GH     
2. AB,"CD,EF",GH
3. AB|CD|EF|GH
4. AB|EF"A" "|GH
```

Expected Output
**Note :** E.g For 1st string, I want `AB CD EF GH` to be 4 different array elements of the same array. Similarly for next i/ps

```
1. AB  CD  EF  GH  
2. AB  "CD,EF"  GH
3. AB  CD  EF  GH
4. AB  EF"A" "  GH
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression?  Splitting on characters seems better/easier here.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? can you give me an example for it ? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the last element, without balanced quotes, split before GH?

Answer (score 0):

From 3) and 4) you want to match sequences of letters not containing `|` characters, while from 1) you want to match sequences of letters not containing commas. And this has to happen at the same time, so that the sequence can't contain either character.

Alternatively, 2) allows the sequence to contain a comma, as long as it begins with a quote, in which case it runs up until the next quote.

Comment: Yes Neil, that is the problem statement. I want to write a common regex that would split the input string into mentioned output array elements.

Comment: I have written a regex which seems to do what I need,   `"(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^\\<delimiter>]+)"`            ...here `<delimiter>` can be replaced by pipe(`|`) or comma(`,`)  ....but it is failing if I have two delimiters following one another without any intermediary text e.g. `AB|CD||EF`  ..expected output here should be `AB CD <blank> EF`..but this is not happening :(

Comment: I think you mean `[^|,]*` (not +) as the second alternative in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is it required for your homework this to be regex? It seems like you can just scan each line character by character and replace the , with a space easily.

Comment: If you notice carefully, the 2nd i/p string ... there I don't want comma(`,`) in between the double quotes to be replaced by space. So replacing is not the solution.

Comment: alright, heres an example:

String s1 = "AB,\"CD,EF\",GH"

Now you will use String.split to split the string with the comma being a seperator. So now your result is:

AB "CD EF" GH

Now run through the string using a for loop and check to see if there is a quote. If there is see if there is a matching quote. If there is a matching quote check between the quotes and see if there is a space. If there is a space then rewrite the string NOT including the space.

Comment: Just seeing the last 2 examples, you should FIRST check to see if the string contains a ','. If not then just split it by | (if it contains the pipe). 

Is there a case where there would be a pipe and a comma in the same string? If so, make sure to program for that.